# wkhtmltopdf margin between body and footer

Tags: html, css, footer, wkhtmltopdf, margins

I am generating a report using wkhtmltopdf, this reports contains texts with a variable length  for this reason I not always can force the page break, sometimes wkhtmltopdf has to do it for me.

I am trying to find out if there is any way of forcing a margin between the footer introduced with wkthtmltopdf (--footer-left foo --footter-right [page]) and the body of the page.

I have already tried with the CSS margin-bottom  but it does not work since it is applied to the end of the html not the page breaking.

And i have also tried the wkhtmltopdf margin bottom "-B 10mm" but it does not work since it is also applied to the footer.

Any clues please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give any fiddle or your tries..! den how should we help.. `put margin:0; if you don't need margin or give some value.. `  this is for your question(this answer is like your question)..

Comment: Sorry you are right. I have tried setting the margin-bottom in the CSS of my HTML but it did not work sice it is aplied over the end of the html page not the page break, I have also tried the wkhtmltopdf margin bottom option "-B 10mm" but also did not work since it is also applied to the footer

Comment: My +1: The -1s are unnecessary as this is a valid question, but some people might think that you have not read the manual for wkhtmltopdf and might -1 because of that. But I know from experience that it's not easily found even if you do read the manual. Also, they might not know what margin you mean and confuse it with the CSS `margin` rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried and tried and the solution for this problem is to use `wkhtmltopdf` flag:

```
--footer-spacing
```

Comment: Had same issue used --footer-spacing but also specified blank html page with nbsp; as the footer using --footer-html

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this problem myself. The `footer-spacing` option is indeed what you want to do. You can also specify a negative amount of spacing if need be (that's what I had to do on my own project).